react-hook-form: reset function call changes in all controllers of page
I have a problem with use reset to clean my form.
When I use that function, my form that have two selects wrapped by Controller, even that I define default value with only one, both did clean.
Can I have way to prevent this?
Example of code:
reset({
  state: ''
});

return (
  <>
    <Controller 
      name='country'
      render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} />}
    />
    <Controller 
      name='state'
      render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} />}
    />
  </>
);


After reset state is '' and country is undefined.
I tried to use reset by passing only one property, but it still didn't work.
The expected result is that it clears only the 'state' Select.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hello There,
The problem you are facing is because of your reset function called on the entire form. To run the reset function on a specific Controller, you may use the callback function.
Below is the code, you may consider. Let me know, if it works for you.
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import Select from 'react-select'; // or any select component you are using

const MyForm = () => {
  const { control, reset, getValues } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      country: 'HerePutYourDefaultValue', // set your default value here
      state: ''
    }
  });

   const handleResetState = () => {
    reset({
    state: '' // Only reset the 'state' field
    });
   };

  return (
    <>
      <Controller
        name="country"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} />}
      />
      <Controller
        name="state"
        control={control}
        render={({ field }) => <Select {...field} />}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleResetState}>
        Reset State
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyForm;

**

Ok, if i destructuring field and pass 'value' and 'onChange' to my Select, with this code above, the problem persist

Could you please provide me your code along with the solution you want so I pay attention to detail and find out the problem.

From react-hook-form documentation, you can pass an object with keys and values to be retained.
Calling reset() in itself, resets the whole form and the values are undefined.
  const defaultValues = { state: '', country: '' };
  const { register, handleSubmit, reset, watch } = useForm({
    defaultValues,
  });

  const handleResetState = () => {
    reset({
      state: '',
      country: defaultValues.country //update the value of country
    });
  };

If you want the value of the country to remain updated, you could use the watch from react-hook-form
const countryValue = watch('country')

const handleResetState = () => {
    reset({
      state: '',
      country: countryValue //update the value of country
    });
  };

